# Updating an array of objects iteratively in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update a couple of objects in the MongoDB in nodejs. Here's the problem I'm having: 
 I have an array of objects kind of looks like this:

```
[{
   "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed611265828aa77c978afb4"
    },
    "advert_id": "5ec2e4a8bda562e21b8c5052",
    "isCategory": false,
    "name": "2+1 Ev Taşıma",
    "value": "2200 TL"
},
{
    "_id": "40", // this object is recently added so it doesn't 
                // have an oid it needs to be inserted instead of updating.
    "advert_id": "5ec2e4a8bda562e21b8c5052",
    "isCategory": false,
    "name": "4+1 Ev Taşıma",
    "value": "7000 TL"
},
]
```

I'm trying to update every one of these objects using `collection.updateMany` with `upsert: true`
Here's the code I wrote:

```js
mongodb.collection('prices').updateMany({}, {$set: post.prices}, {upsert: true}, (error, result) => {
    if(error) throw error;
    res.json(response);
})
```

Here's the error:

```
MongoError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead. For example: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} not 
{$set: [ { _id: "5ed611265828aa77c978afb4", advert_id: "5ec2e4a8bda562e21b8c5052", isCategory: false, name: "2+1 
Ev Taşıma", value: "2000 TL", isVisible: false } ]}
```

The problem seems that I'm trying to pass prices array directly into the $set pipe. What's a field type and how can I translate my array into that.

Appreciate the help, had some difficult time searching through the documentation but couldn't find any related chapter. I can really appreciate it if you can also link the documentation's related part in your answer.

Database document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ed611265828aa77c978afb4"
    },
    "advert_id": "5ec2e4a8bda562e21b8c5052",
    "isCategory": false,
    "name": "2+1 Ev Taşıma",
    "value": "2000 TL",
    "isVisible": false
}
```

Comment: can you please explain some more so i can help you.
Like which answer you want  & document example .

Comment: I'd like to update every element in the array I mentioned at the beginning of the question. I want each one of them to be upserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a problem here `{$set: post.prices}`

It should be `{$set: {'prices':post.prices}}` - You should provide a document to `$set`

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```
    db.col.find({
  '_id.$oid': '5ed611265828aa77c978afb4'
},
{
  $set: {
    "advert_id": "5ec2e4a8bda562e21b8c5052",
    "isCategory": false
  },
  {
    upsert: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, the error is not shown now but still, I can't update the document. I updated the question, so you can see how my document is in the database.

Comment: What do you want to upset? Can you add the value to be inserted to which field? And type of the fields better sample of prices/post

Comment: I updated the array so you can see differences clearly. I have a collection called ```prices```. Also, I have an array that I mentioned in the beginning. I'd like to iterate in the array and if it can be updated (if it has an oid) i want to update it and if it doesn't have an oid I want to insert it.

Comment: Query part is clear. Once queried, what do you want to upsert?

Comment: In the first code block, there's an array I want to upsert every item of it.